# Improper typecasting in Class constructor

Tags: c++, class, casting

I'm new to C++ and I have a problem with classes.

I got this prototype

```
class MMA7455 : public Accel
{
public:
    MMA7455(uint8_t);
    uint8_t accel_get_data(acceleration_t*);
private:
    uint8_t accel_data_ready(void);
};
```

and I want to create an instance of it

```
MMA7455 accel = MMA7455(0x21);
```

but the following message appears

```
In function `global constructors keyed to accel':
sensors.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `MMA7455::MMA7455(unsigned char)'
```

Why it's looking for 'unsigned char' argument? Same message even if I try to implicitly cast the type of constant

```
MMA7455 accel = MMA7455((uint8_t)0x21);
```

Comment: Right, the problem was in bad linker settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't link your .cpp file containing the constructor definition. "uint8_t" is a typedef for 'unsigned char".

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `MMA7455::MMA7455(uint8_t)` somewhere in your program, i.e. add a `{}`-body after the definition in the prototype (or perhaps you just forgot to compile and link the cpp-file containing the definitions for `MMA7455`.

It looks for `unsigned char` because `uint8_t` happens to be a `typedef` for `unsigned char` on your system.

Comment: I've defined it as `MMA7455::MMA7455(uint8_t i2cAddress)
{
    this->m_Address = i2cAddress;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`uint8_t` is a typedef for `unsigned char` on your platform. The error is a linker error since you haven't provided an implementation for your constructor and is unrelated to the argument being an `unsigned char` or not.

Comment: I've defined it as `MMA7455::MMA7455(uint8_t i2cAddress) { this->m_Address = i2cAddress; }`

Comment: @marvin: Are you linking that file properly?